# Hide managed metadata column in document information pannel

Tags: managed-metadata, document-info-panel

I am trying to hide a managed metadata column in the document information panel. I attempted to do this by setting the ShowInFileDlg property of the field to false however the field still shows. I've used this same approch on a multiline text field and that worked fine?

Comment: I have the same problem - any solution? Is this a bug? The same applies for Hidden="TRUE".

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a bug. I have not found solution but I have workaround. I have split my content type into 2 content types. One has managed metadata columns I do not want to be displayed in DIP and another has columns that should be displayed. I added these 2 content types to my library and assigned the one without managed metadata to my documents. After that, I have all columns available in library for document and only the one I want are displayed in DIP. This workaround has one limitation: columns hidden in this manner will not show up in standard form (is my scenario this is OK for me).

Answer (score 0):

Old topic but maybe it will help somone - here is confirmation that this is a bug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24284773/how-to-hide-sharepoint-2013-managed-metadata-column-in-document-information-pane